# Left joining table with existing data negative match

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (`TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC`) set up like this:

```
ID| TYPE_ID| GOOD_ID 
1 |   1    |   2
```

Another table (`X`) is like this:

```
ID| GOOD_NAME          | GOOD_ID 
1 |   'Something'      |   1
1 |   'Something else' |   2
```

I have both `GOOD_ID` and `TYPE_ID`, and am trying to `left join` `X` to `TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC` to find the records with certain `TYPE_ID` that are not present in the table. Here is a part of the query:

```
SELECT * FROM table X
LEFT JOIN TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC on TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC.GOOD_ID = X.GOOD_ID
WHERE TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC.GOOD_ID is NULL AND TYPE_ID = 2
```

I don't get anything back. And maybe I m not writing the query right. Since I have existing entries with `TYPE_1`, I m looking for the `GOOD_ID`(s) where `TYPE_ID` is 2 and they don't have entry in the `TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC` table. What am I doing wrong here?

Desired result is :

`1 |   'Something'      |   1` - which is `ID 1` from Table `X`

Comment: What is the wanted result?

Comment: hi @ypercubeᵀᴹ I updated the question. thanks

Comment: And why s the `1 |   'Something else' |   2` not to be returned? It's not associated with any row with `type_id=2` either.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ That's what I want the data that is note associated, sorry for being poor at explaining

Comment: Based on your tables as shown, TYPE_ID is a column in table TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC.

So, you're looking for rows from table X, where there are matching rows in TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC with TYPE_ID = 2 and GOOD_ID = NULL. If (as I assume) GOOD_ID happens to be a NOT NULL column, you're not going to find any.

Your sample data doesn't include any rows where TYPE_ID = 2, so that would be an issue as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a simple anti-semijoin. Either with `LEFT JOIN - IS NULL`:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM table_X AS x
    LEFT JOIN TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC AS g
    ON g.GOOD_ID = x.GOOD_ID
WHERE g.GOOD_ID IS NULL ;
```

or with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM table_X AS x
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT 1
        FROM TYPE_GOODS_ASSOC AS g
        WHERE g.GOOD_ID = x.GOOD_ID
      ) ;
```